# querying across multiple fields and returning minimum values of sets

Tags: sql

I have a complex (at least for me!) SQL question that I've been trying to solve.

The structure of my table is:

```
Query: describe shipping_zones
+------------+--------+---------+
| name       | type   | comment |
+------------+--------+---------+
| key_id     | int    |         |
| carrier    | string |         |
| origin_zip | int    |         |
| dest_zip   | int    |         |
| zone       | int    |         |
+------------+--------+---------+
```

There are 3 types of "carriers"

```
Query: select DISTINCT(carrier) FROM shipping_zones
+---------+
| carrier |
+---------+
| fedex   |
| ups     |
| usps    |
+---------+
Fetched 3 row(s) in 0.42s
```

I have this query that finds returns two zones for each carrier:

```
SELECT carrier, zone
FROM shipping_zones
WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = 978;

+---------+------+
| carrier | zone |
+---------+------+
| ups     | 4    |
| ups     | 7    |
| fedex   | 7    |
| fedex   | 4    |
| usps    | 8    |
| usps    | 4    |
+---------+------+
```

The problem is I only want to return the lowest number from each carrier, not both. Can I use Min() or is there some better way to do it?

Thanks for the help, I appreciate the help in understanding SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for aggregate functions.  However, whenever you use an aggregate function you have to tell your database engine what to do with all of the fields individually.  If you have a text field you just want collapsed wherever there are duplicates you can use the group by clause.

```
SELECT carrier, min(zone)
FROM shipping_zones
WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = 978
group by carrier;
```

Comment: ok thank you, that is what I thought. When I try what you wrote though, I am getting a syntax error that it says I'm missing a group by clause even though it is there?

Comment: Have you removed your previous semicolon after the where clause?

Comment: yep. this is what I'm running:
SELECT carrier, origin_zip AS distribution_center, min(zone) AS min_zone
FROM shipping_zones
WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) AND dest_zip = 978
GROUP BY carrier;

Comment: Looks like you added an extra field, but I'm glad you got it working. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165452/discussion-between-william-and-gerik).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Min() function on each carrier after you group by carriers. Grouping will essentially "summarize" the column that you want to group by (carrier, in this case) by the function that you apply ("Min", in this case):

```sql
SELECT carrier, MIN(zone) as min_zone
FROM shipping_zones
WHERE (origin_zip = 402 OR origin_zip = 950) 
AND dest_zip = 978
GROUP BY carrier
```